# How to prevent user to disable or delete my IOS safari content blocker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, mobile-development

Now,  Iam working on a project to build an app with content blocker extension which will be integrated with safari to block some websites from loading and this will be controlled by parents to safe thier child s from accessing those sites.  The challenge which I face that childs may disable it from safari setting by swipe the content blocker button in settings or delete the app. 
How I allow parents to protect the app?

This needed function is the same like done in below link:
https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id1071244095

Comment: Still not clear in your question, Please explain in more detail way..   :)

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with Content Blocker and unfortunately you can't do that. :(